# How can I insert a button in the third row of a GridLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

How can I insert a button in the third row of a `GridLayout`? Currently with the code below does not work. Thanks a lot!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
      android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:rowCount="5"
       tools:context=".GridXMLActivity">
       
        <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
           android:layout_width="160dp"
           android:layout_height="90dp"
           android:layout_row="3" />
       
 
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default a `GridLayout` item dimension is considered to be 0dp; So, in your case placing a button in the third row will behave as if it's in the first row, as both first & second rows have 0dp height.

Also, if you have nothing to put in the first and second rows, it doesn't make sense to use the third row; while it's supposed to be in the first one.

So, to fix this, you probably need dummy views/spaces in the first & second rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="5">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1" />

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridLayout like below. But try to use RecycleView with GridLayoutManager for highly customisation.

```
// 2 Columns and 4 Rows
 <GridLayout
   android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:columnCount="2"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:rowCount="4"
   tools:context=".GridXMLActivity"
   tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="56dp"
   tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

 // First Row
 <View .. />
 <View .. />

 // Second Row
 <View .. />
 <View .. />

 // Third Row
 <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
       android:layout_width="160dp"
       android:layout_height="90dp" /></GridLayout>
```